Cannot make a delete request(help)
So im creating an api(with no database),right now im preacticing making GET,POST,and DELETE requests,wehn making GET and POST request it works just fine but when i add the id of the spacidic item i want to delete ,postman gives me a "Cannot DELETE /api/write/Avv8RZNxm" ("Avv8RZNxm" being the id)error.Ive also console.log ed it and the id does show up in my console .Im using postman to retrive the responses .
import express from "express";
import shortid from "shortid";
import cors from "cors";

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const PORT = 4000;

let channels = [];
const lessons = [];

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ hello: "WORLD" });
});

app.get("/hello", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ hello: "Future senior dev" });
});

app.post("/api/write", (req, res) => {
  const channelInfo = req.body;
  channelInfo.id = shortid.generate();
  channels.push(channelInfo);
  // res.status(201);
  console.log(channelInfo);
  try {
    const response = channelInfo;
    res.status(200).json({ response });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});

app.get("/api/write", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json(channels);
});

app.delete("/api/channels/:id", (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  // console.log("ID to delete:", id);
  // console.log("Channels before DELETE:", channels);

  const deleted = channels.find((channels) => channels.id === id); //go into this array (channels) find and return to me the channel where the channel id in the array matches the one we passing in on tthis (line 42)req.params and stick it in this variable(this line)
  if (deleted) {
    console.log(deleted);
    channels = channels.filter((channels) => channels.id !== id); //!==(is not equal) //return to us a brand new channels array minus the id of the one we passed in here (app.delete("/api/channels/:id", (req, res) =>)
    res.status(200).json(deleted);
  } else {
    console.log(deleted);
    res
      .status(404)
      .json({ message: "Channel you are looking for does not exist" }); //else say hey i cant find it
  }
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log(`\n Server Running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});


I have tried changing the code,using re.body instead of re.params ,tried an if else statemnt inside a catch statemant and nothing has worked .

You are sending delete request to wrong endpoint in Postman, based on your implementation:
app.delete("/api/channels/:id", (req, res) => {
    // implementation removed!
});

The Postman route should be:
/api/channels/Avv8RZNxm

